# Remove Proprietary Driver Installed in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia

I recently installed this driver https://github.com/Frogging-Family/nvidia-all with the instruction on their page. But I want to uninstall it now and use the official one. How would I go about doing that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Hope someone will come upon this with use in the far future.

Answer (score 0):

So their drivers also work with pacman as ones from the repos do. Just install the regular nvidia drivers, it will remove all conflicting files from there.